# Strange UIView.animateWithDuration compilation error if have some code in animations block

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, xcode6, animatewithduration

I have code

`UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.4,
            options: .Repeat, animations: {
//                self.circle.center += 10
            }, completion: nil)
    }`

which compiles.
But if I uncomment line
`self.circle.center += 10` I would have ViewController.swift:28:23: Could not find member 'Repeat'.

self.circle is `@IBOutlet var circle: Circle!`
 connected to certain object on Main.storyboard.
Circle is class extending UIView with custom drawRect.

What 's wrong with all of this stuff?

Comment: center is CGPoint so you can not += 10, you need to increment its x or y property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add `+10` to the center point you would need to do something like this:

```
self.circle.center.x += 10
self.circle.center.y += 10
```

The center property is a `CGPoint` containing an `x` and `y` value. So adding `+10` to the just the center alone doesn't really make sense.

```
struct CGPoint {
    var x: CGFloat
    var y: CGFloat
}
```

Comment: To be quite honest I have no idea. Currently I still prefer to use Objective-C for this reason. Swift is still new and weird errors occur with it in Xcode.